# Move some method from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I have 6 pictures on my `View` like `Xaml.Image`. I need move, rotate and scale it. This is my `xaml` code of 1 image for e.g.

```
<Image Width="525"
Height="331"
Canvas.Top="-199"
Canvas.Left="-733"
x:Name="CollageImg1"
ManipulationMode="All"
Source="{Binding CollageImg1}"
ManipulationDelta="CollageImgage1_Manipulation">
<Image.RenderTransform>
<CompositeTransform/>
</Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

I have method `collageImgage1_Manipulation` for each image in codebehind for all my manipulation.

```
private void CollageImgage1_Manipulation(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageManipulator.Manipulation(e, CollageImg1);
    }
```

And general method for all images

```
public static void Manipulation(ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e, Image xamlimage)
    {
        CompositeTransform ct = (CompositeTransform)xamlimage.RenderTransform;
        ct.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
        ct.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
        ct.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        ct.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        ct.Rotation += Math.PI * e.Delta.Rotation;
    }
```

I try to make `Command` but i dont know how to transfer `ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs` and `Xaml.Image` to my method in other class

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: The old code does not work in UWP / WP8.1 but only in WPF!**

Instead I created a class deriving from `ContentControl` that supports firing a command when the `ManipulationDelta` event has been raised. Though there might be a more precise name describing the action of the class, I called it `ManipulationContentControl`.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

public class ManipulationContentControl
    : ContentControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ManipulationCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(ManipulationCommand),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(ManipulationContentControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public ICommand ManipulationCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(ManipulationCommandProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ManipulationCommandProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then I created a class for the arguments passed to the command.

```
public class ManipulationCommandArgs
{
    public ManipulationCommandArgs(
        CompositeTransform target,
        ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(target, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));
        }

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(eventArgs, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventArgs));
        }

        this.Target = target;
        this.EventArgs = eventArgs;
    }

    public CompositeTransform Target { get; private set; }

    public ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs EventArgs { get; private set; }
}
```

After that I needed to implement the event handler for my `ManipulationContentControl` class.

```
public ManipulationContentControl()
{
    this.ManipulationDelta += this.ManipulationImage_ManipulationDelta;
}


private void ManipulationImage_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var transform = this.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

    if (object.ReferenceEquals(e, null) ||
        object.ReferenceEquals(transform, null))
    {
        return;
    }

    var args = new ManipulationCommandArgs(transform, e);

    if (this.ManipulationCommand?.CanExecute(args) == true)
    {
        this.ManipulationCommand.Execute(args);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can use the `ManipulationContentControl` class in your XAML and embed an `Image` in it. **All properties associated with manipulation should be applied to the `ManipulationContentControl` instead of the `Image`!**

*This example assumes that the `ManipulationContentControl` class is located in the same namespace as the XAML code.*

```
<local:ManipulationContentControl ManipulationCommand="{Binding YourCommand}" ManipulationMode="All">
    <local:ManipulationContentControl.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform />
    </local:ManipulationContentControl.RenderTransform>
    <Image ... />
</local:ManipulationContentControl>
```

For `{Binding YourCommand}` you should implement the [`RelayCommand` class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute). The `RelayCommand` class in this tutorial should also work for UWP and WP8/8.1.

Then create an instance of the `RelayCommand` class that contains the method that manipulates the code.

```
public RelayCommand YourCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand(
    arg =>
    {
        var param = arg as ManipulationCommandArgs;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(arg, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(); // or return
        }

        // below you can insert your manipulation code as in your event handler,
        // but use 'param.Target' instead of 'ct' and 'param.EventArgs.Delta' instead of 'e.Delta'
    });
```

I hope these code snippets work for you!

Edit: my solution works for UWP because there is no integrated `Behavior<T>` support, but in WPF you should prefer behaviors for UI actions, as [MichaelThePotato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6521806/michaelthepotato) described.

This article might help you: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/30/xaml-behaviors-open-source-and-on-uwp/. It announces the availability of behaviors for UWP apps through a NuGet package published by Microsoft. If this package works fine, you should prefer MichaelThePotato's solution over this.

Comment: What namespace for `Image` if i use `System.Windows.Input;` i have "`cannot derive from sealed type Image`"

Comment: Sorry I confused the WPF definition of the Image class, where the description indicates that it can be derived, with the UWP definition. I will update my answer to not derive from Image but rather implement a control containing an Image control.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would probably be via a Behavior.
If you're working on WPF -

```
internal class ManipulationDeltaCommandBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    public ICommand ManipulationDeltaCommand { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.ManipulationDelta += OnManipulationDelta;
    }

    private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        ManipulationDeltaCommand.Execute(e);
    }
}
```

This way you can pass the event and its parameters to the VM.
Or better yet, do all the UI work in the UI via the behavior! I think that's much better.

```
internal class ManipulationDeltaCommandBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.ManipulationDelta += OnManipulationDelta;
    }

    private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do the work here! AssociatedObject is the Image
    }
}
```